# Problem displaying accented characters in Sublime Text

Tags: encoding, sublimetext, sublimetext4

When I type accented characters in the editor (Sublime Text build 4113 on Windows 10) it looks ok like this:

[image: typing]

I saved it with utf-8 encoding and closed it, but when the file is opened again the characters can't be displayed correctly:
[image: reopened]

The file can be displayed correctly in Notepad though.

I tried "reopen with encoding utf-8" but nothing changed (I have `"default_encoding": "UTF-8"` in my settings). Is there anything wrong with my sublime text settings or should I save it in some other way? I don't know why sublime text always open files with these characters in a .dump file, usually it doesn't open small files this way.

I'm pasting the characters before and after reopening of the file below:
çàéèâîôûêïëäüöÿœ 莽脿茅猫芒卯么没锚茂毛盲眉枚每艙

---

Edit:

Finally I noticed that there's something wrong with an old deprecated package which is causing the problem. Whenever I open a file containing accented characters the old `GBK-Support` package tries to convert the file to a `.dump` file and end up with an error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/sublime_text/Lib/python33/sublime_plugin.py", line 892, in on_close
    callback(v)
  File "/opt/sublime_text/Lib/python33/sublime_plugin.py", line 152, in profiler
    return event_handler(*args)
  File "/home/stormy/.config/sublime-text-3/Installed Packages/GBK Support.sublime-package/sublime_gbk.py", line 58, in on_close
    if ".dump" in view.file_name():
TypeError: argument of type 'NoneType' is not iterable
```

which converts all the accented characters in the `.dump` file (but not in the original one, which is why reloading with encoding wouldn't help).

Simply removing this package solved the problem.

Comment: Are you *sure* you saved it with *just* UTF8 encoding? You didn't use a BOM (LE or BE), or UTF-16 LE or BE with or without a BOM?

Comment: Open your user preferences and add `"show_encoding": true,` to it. It will now show the encoding of the current file in the bottom status bar.

Comment: Well, I did check with `file enc_test.txt` and it returns `enc_test.txt: Unicode text, UTF-8 text, with no line terminators`. The `show_encoding` option is turned on, but it shows `UTF-8`. Seems like the file is always displayed as GBK encoding, even after "reopen with encoding UTF-8".